# How to downgrade software using terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, downgrade

New apple user here, I am trying to downgrade matplotlib to 1.3.1 after coming to this potential solution:

https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3470/

I just have no idea how to do that.

Comment: It depends on how you installed it in the first place. A naive solution would be to uninstall, then install the older version.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
pip uninstall matplotlib
pip install matplotlib==1.3.1
```